# WSO2IS 5.10.0 - Error for updating user in active directory user store with multiple DN

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

For a client, we need to configure an Active-Directory user store inside WSO2IS 5.10.0 with users stored in 3 differents Organizational Unit (OU).
For that we have created an Active-Directory user store and for the `User Search Base` (DN) we have set the following value:
 `OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Union COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Utilisateurs,OU=company_web,DC=companysiege,DC=local`

It's work perfectly for reading user but when updating a user we have the following error on web interface:

> Error while updating profile of AD-COMPANY/user@example.fr.
> Error is: Results could not be retrieved from the directory context for user : 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878

With the following logs in wso2carbon.log file:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,535] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.connector.scim2.SCIM2ProvisioningConnector} - password : 58fd4e7e-477a-4fb1-b42a-2f4866b769f9,userName : /user@example.fr,urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:{accountLocked : false,country : France,newsletter : true,addresses : ,firstname : UserFirstName,birthdate : 1979-10-18,city : ,mailing_marketing : true,telephone : +00000000000,brochurelegs : false,radio : National,lastname : UserLastName,postalcode : ,favorite_radio : 63,addresses2 : ,civilite : M}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,701] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users with Property: objectGuid SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\57\13\49\9f\12\fd\ca\43\89\60\30\7b\e3\00\78\78))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,701] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\57\13\49\9f\12\fd\ca\43\89\60\30\7b\e3\00\78\78)) in SearchBase:
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,701] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :mail
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,701] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :sn
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,701] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users. SearchBase: OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Union COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Utilisateurs,OU=company_web,DC=companysiege,DC=local Constructed-Filter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\57\13\49\9f\12\fd\ca\43\89\60\30\7b\e3\00\78\78))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,702] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Search controls. Max Limit: 100 Max Time: 10000
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,702] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_IP:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,865] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - mail : user@example.fr
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,868] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - result: user@example.fr
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,869] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Union COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Utilisateurs,OU=company_web,DC=companysiege,DC=local
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:43,870] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_IP:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,043] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(mail=user@example.fr)) in SearchBase:
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,044] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :accountLock
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,068] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Active Directory timestamp attributes: [whenCreated, whenChanged]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,068] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Retrieved user store properties before type conversions: {}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,068] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Converted timestamp attribute values: {}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,068] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Retrieved user store properties after type conversions: {}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,069] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_id_from_user_name_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER, found the entry: 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878 for the key: AD-EXAMPLE/user@example.fr successfully.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,087] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Retrieved user store properties for update: {mail=user@example.fr, extensionAttribute2=63, extensionAttribute1=1979-10-18, extensionAttribute4=true, givenName=UserFirstName, assistant=, extensionAttribute3=true, postalCode=, mobile=+00000000000, extensionAttribute5=false, title=M, l=, co=France, whenChanged=2021-05-10T15:43:43.501774Z, division=National, postalAddress=, streetAddress=, objectGuid=9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878, profileConfiguration=default, sn=UserLastName}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,088] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Skipping Active Directory maintained default attributes: [objectGuid, whenCreated, whenChanged, lastLogonTimestamp]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,089] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_IP:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,222] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserUniqueIDDomainResolver} - Cache miss for user id: 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878 searching from the database.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,225] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_name_from_user_id_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER, found the entry: AD-EXAMPLE/user@example.fr for the key: 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878 successfully.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,248] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} - Results could not be retrieved from the directory context for user : 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878 javax.naming.InvalidNameException: OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Union COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Utilisateurs,OU=company_web,DC=companysiege,DC=local: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349, best match of:
        'OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Union COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Utilisateurs,OU=company_web,DC=companysiege,DC=local'

        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3198)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2996)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_lookup(LdapCtx.java:1062)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_lookup(ComponentContext.java:542)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:177)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserAttributesWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:969)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValuesWithID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4029)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3965)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.mgt.UserProfileAdmin.setUserProfile(UserProfileAdmin.java:162)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.stub.UserProfileMgtServiceStub.setUserProfile(UserProfileMgtServiceStub.java:529)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient.setUserProfile(UserProfileCient.java:68)
        at org.apache.jsp.userprofile.edit_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(edit_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:268)        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,263] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} - Results could not be retrieved from the directory context for user : 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878 org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.mgt.UserProfileException: Results could not be retrieved from the directory context for user : 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.mgt.UserProfileAdmin.setUserProfile(UserProfileAdmin.java:166)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.stub.UserProfileMgtServiceStub.setUserProfile(UserProfileMgtServiceStub.java:529)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient.setUserProfile(UserProfileCient.java:68)
        at org.apache.jsp.userprofile.edit_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(edit_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:268)        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Results could not be retrieved from the directory context for user : 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserAttributesWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:986)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValuesWithID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4029)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3965)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.mgt.UserProfileAdmin.setUserProfile(UserProfileAdmin.java:162)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Union COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Utilisateurs,OU=company_web,DC=companysiege,DC=local: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349, best match of:
        'OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Union COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local#OU=Utilisateurs,OU=company_web,DC=companysiege,DC=local'

        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3198)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2996)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_lookup(LdapCtx.java:1062)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_lookup(ComponentContext.java:542)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:177)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserAttributesWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:969)
        ... 82 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-10 15:43:44,304] [bc3017b2-963b-41fd-b21a-f6edf57ae5da] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} - org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Results could not be retrieved from the directory context for user : 9f491357-fd12-43ca-8960-307be3007878
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you for any suggestions.